# DATEDIFF in SPARK SQl

Tags: apache-spark-sql, datediff

I am new to Spark SQL. We are migrating data from SQL server to Databricks.
I am using SPARK SQL . Can you please suggest how to achieve below functionality in SPARK sql for the below datefunctions. I can see datediff gives only days in spark sql.

```sql
DATEDIFF(YEAR,StartDate,EndDate)
DATEDIFF(Month,StartDate,EndDate) 
DATEDIFF(Quarter,StartDate,EndDate)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As you have mentioned SparkSQL does support `DATEDIFF` but for days only.  I would also be careful as it seems the parameters are the opposite way round for Spark, ie

```
--SQL Server
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

--Spark
DATEDIFF ( enddate , startdate )
```

Spark does however support a similar function called `months_between` which you could use in place of `DATEDIFF( month ...`.  This function also returns a decimal amount so optionally cast it to `INT` for similar functionality to the

```
SELECT startDate, endDate, 
  DATEDIFF( endDate, startDate ) AS diff_days,
  CAST( months_between( endDate, startDate ) AS INT ) AS diff_months      
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 1;
```

There are also `year` and `quarter` functions for determining the year and quarter of a date respectively.  You could simply minus the years but quarters would be more tricky.  It may be you have to 'do the math' or end up using a calendar table.

Comment: Thanks very much. It really helps. Yes, Quarter difference looks tricky.

Comment: Just to clarify SQL server seems to require DATEDIFF (datepart, recentDate, olderDate) as startdate and enddate are a bit nebulous.

Answer (score 4):

As Spark doesn't provide the other unit, I use below method,

```
select 
    (bigint(to_timestamp(endDate))) - (bigint(to_timestamp(startDate))) as time_diff
```

This results in the second unit, so dividing by 60 or 3600 can transform the units.

Answer (score 0):

Recent updates in Spark support datediff(endDate,StartDate) and returns the days.